# Public boolean isnamevalid() with charAt(i)

Tags: java, swing, boolean, indexof

```
String name = jTextField3.getText();

for(int i = 0; i <= name.length(); i++)
    if (name.charAt(i) >= "0")
        return false;
return false;
```

The first method should find numbers in jTextField3. If there are numbers so it will return false if no so true. Another method if the first method == false so JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Name isn't valid");. the proplem is the second method isn't working

```
if (isNameValid == false)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Name isn't valid");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work for me"? Does your computer crash? Explain what you think should happen, and then tell us what happens instead. Your first example always returns false, so why bother with the loop? Also, you should not use == to compare to true or false. Just use "if (!isNameValie)"

Comment: i edited it now its explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. But if you want to check the length of the TextField you can do this:

```
    String name = jTextField3.getText();

    public boolean isNameValid(String name){
      if (name.length > 0){
          return true;
      } else {
         return false;
       }
    }

if (isNameValid(name)){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Name isn't valid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your entire method looks like this (as you left out the header):

```
public boolean isNameValid()
{
    String name = jTextField3.getText();

    for(int i=0 ; i<=name.length() ; i++)
        if ( name.charAt(i) >= 0 )
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

One note, your method is not marked with the keyword `static`, which means that it is an instance method. Seeing how in your call, you do not instantiate or invoke an object, I assume you probably mean to write a class method. To make it a class method, you must change your header to say:

```
public static Boolean isNameValid()
```

If you don't make it `static`, you need to create an object of whatever class you are in, and then call the method with the object name. Or say `this.isNameValid()`.

**Assuming you make it a class method:**

The problem is that you are not properly calling the method. You are saying `isNameValid` when you should be saying `isNameValid()`. Even when you don't have any arguments, you still need the `()` so the IDE can recognize that you are calling a method. Once you make that change, you can just call it by saying:

`if(isNameValid())`

Comment: No i did it on anothe method like
else if(isNameValid()==false)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Name isn't valid");
and in the first problem its showing me a problem that i need to add a return statement

Comment: Oh, that's because you probably have a return statement for the IF-loop, but if the IF-loop doesn't execute, there is no return statement. So, outside of everything else, you must say return (true/false);